# move the main Hard Drive and Ram from HP laptop to Lenovo

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, laptop, memory, ramdisk

My HP laptop got damaged and cost a lot to fix so I decided to use it as parts.

Anyways, I was searching if I am able to move the hard drive and ram from hp laptop to Lenovo, but, I couldn't find a clear answer about that.

I hope you guys know if that is fine or it could cause an issue.

Comment: Without detailed information like the specific models of the laptops, type of RAM, type of hard drive and connectors(SATA, m2, nvme, etc) no help can be given.  Please update your question with the details about the systems and parts.

Comment: Well, you don't get my questions right. I just want to know is it possible to move the hard drive from a device to another or it's forbidden???? That's it. nothing tricky :) BTW, no one forced you to answer

Comment: Nothing forbids you from doing so but if connections don't work then there is no point in trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard drive - probably. The ports that connect hard drives are pretty standard across PC laptops (SATA), and specs about hard-drives in general are pretty agnostic.  You could even plug in your laptop hard-drive into a desktop. The biggest possible limitation would be form factor, but you won't know until you get in there.  I doubt this would be a problem.  There is the rare case that you have PCIe hard-drive, and in such case, this would ports would be a problem.

RAM - probably not. Many more variables at work here. If your laptops were built within the same year or two, then maybe. RAM for a particular machine can usually only work with particular set of specs. Also, laptop RAM can have different form factors and different contacts between manufacturers even if the specs are the same.  But all this should be easy to check.  Usually RAM is the most easily removable component.  If you can take it out, and it fits in the new laptop, and the computer boots, then its compatible.